# Inherently reflexive verbs

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar

What is the status of *herself* in the following sentence?

Mary behaved herself during the class.

Is *herself* an internal argument? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: _Behave oneself_ is an English idiom meaning to not call attention to oneself by performing inappropriate actions. _Behave yourself now!_ is what you say to children and alcoholic adults before entering a party site. As an idiom chunk, you can call the reflexive anything you want; "internal argument" is a nice question-begging term.

Comment: Thank you for the explanatory comment! I was wondering what is the well-accepted analysis of reflexives of inherently reflexive verbs.

Comment: What other "inherently reflexive verbs" are there? All the other examples I can think of are ordinary transitives, that can take an object. Sometimes when the object is reflexive they have a special meaning, but they are not like _behave_ which is otherwise intransitive.

Comment: @Colin Fine. While English has many fewer of them than related languages (e.g. German, French), there are nevertheless a number of them that can be acknowledged, e.g. _perjure oneself_, _be oneself_, _be beside oneself_, _feel oneself_, _ingratiate oneself to_, _content oneself with_, _enjoy oneself_, etc.

Comment: Not sure whether *brace oneself* is also inherently reflexive.

Comment: Do inherently reflexive verbs mean that the predicates are already indicating reflexivity without the help of "oneself" to reflexivize the predicate?

Comment: @TimOsborne do we need to distinguish the two situations of inherently reflexive predicate and idiomatic predicate? But those seeming to be inherently reflexive verbs are looking like idiomatic structures just as jlawler has pointed out.

Comment: @Buffoon. Yes, _brace oneself for_ is another example.

Comment: @Xia.Yili, If the number of predicates that behave in the way described is large enough, it becomes a category of predicate rather than just a loose collection of idiosyncratic expressions. The relevant point in this area concerns the frequent occurrence of these necessarily reflexive predicates in other languages. There are many many more of them in languages related to English. For me, it is therefore a category of predicate that can and should be acknowledged.

Comment: @TimOsborne Thanks for your clarification!